# Default Constructor C++ with a header and cpp

Tags: c++, constructor, default

So I have this exercise which is to create a default constructor DayOfYear, which will set someday to the 1st of January. So this constructor it's going to be called by the following main:

```
int main()
{
    DayOfYear someDay;  

    someDay.output();
    return 0;
}
```

so I have this header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
class DayOfYear
{
public:
    int month;
    int day;
    void output();
    DayOfYear();

};
```

and the following cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "DayOfYear.h"
using namespace std;

DayOfYear::DayOfYear() :month(1), day(1)
{

}
```

so I'm getting many errors and I've tried many things but I cant figure out what's the problem.  these errors are;

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
DayOfYear.h:9: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘output’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 DayOfYear:: output();
                    ^
DayOfYear.h:9: error: extra qualification ‘DayOfYear::’ on member ‘output’ [-fpermissive]
 DayOfYear:: output();
 ^
In file included from DayOfYear.cpp:3:
DayOfYear.h:9: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘output’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 DayOfYear:: output();
                    ^
DayOfYear.h:9: error: extra qualification ‘DayOfYear::’ on member ‘output’ [-fpermissive]
 DayOfYear:: output();
```

Comment: It is better to have `int month` etc as private - then use getters/setters

Comment: Where is `void output()` definition ?

Comment: Your error messages do not seem to match the code you are showing.

Comment: The error message says that you have "DayOfYear::" in front of your output() declaration, and that you don't have a return type there. Visual Studio will accept the DayOfYear:: in a class (but it is technically wrong) so that may be why it's there. No return type was never valid C++, but it has been valid C and some (especially old) C++ compilers accept it regardless, implying int. One thing you can check is if it is using the DayOfYear.h that it thinks you're using (try "Open definition" on the include line).

Comment: You don't have some strict compiler options? Try define output `void output(void);`

Comment: @AslakBerby - adding the `void` argument list isn't required and won't affect this.

Comment: I just looked at the error. However some googling gives lot of suggestions on the error. One is related to `using namespace...` Worth a try to comment it out.

Comment: @EdHeal, no it is not! It is just another cargo cult.

Comment: @SergeyA: Only if the setter does no range check, or more generally does not enforce the class invariant. A simple `void set(int month) { this->month = month; }` is indeed pretty useless.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, could not agree more.

Comment: His class header file has no header guard: it is missing either `#ifndef #define ... #endif` or `#pragma once` also he may be getting circular includes since he is including both `<iostream>` and `<cstdlib>` in both the header and cpp files. To avoid this remove them from the header and leave them in the class's cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

I can not answer your question as to the error messages you are getting for I use a completely different compiler, however, this should fix your problems and should work on any standard compiler.

Try writing your class as such:

**DayOfYear.h**

```
#ifndef DAY_OF_YEAR_H
#define DAY_OF_YEAR_H

class DayOfYear {
private:
    int m_day;
    int m_month;

public:
     DayOfYear(); // Default Constructor
     explicit DayOfYear( int month = 1, int day = 1 ); // Constructor With Default Arguments

     void setDay( int day );
     void setMonth( int month );

     int getDay()   const;
     int getMonth() const;

     void display() const;  

private:
     DayOfYear( const DayOfYear& c ); // Not Implemented
     DayOfYear& operator=( const DayOfYear& c ); // Not Implemented
}; // DayOfYear

#endif // DAY_OF_YEAR_H
```

**DayOfYear.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "DayOfYear.h"

// DayOfYear() - Default Constructor
DayOfYear::DayOfYear() :
m_day( 1 ),
m_month( 1 ) {
} // DayOfYear

// DayOfYear() - Constructor with default parameters
// If no values are passed it will default to 1-1
DayOfYear::DayOfYear( int month, int day ) :
m_day( day ),
m_month( month ) {
} // DayOfYear

// setDay()
void DayOfYear::setDay( int day ) {
    m_day = day;
} // setDay()

// setMonth()
void DayOfYear::setMonth( int month ) {
    m_month = month;
} // month

// getDay()
int DayOfYear::getDay() const {
    return = m_day;
} // getDay

// getMonth()
int DayOfYear::getMonth() const {
    return = m_month;
}

// display()
void DayOfYear::display() const {
    std::cout << "Month: " << m_month << " - " 
              << "Day: " << m_day << std::endl;
} // display
```

Now you can write out the display function to any text format that you prefer or are required to do, but this is a valid example that will compile, build and run without errors.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "DayOfYear.h"

int main() {

    DayOfYear someDay;
    someDay.display();

    return 0;

} // main
```